# ansible python API to setup vars without local yml files

Tags: python, ansible

I've read some examples about how to use ansible python API. some examples works rely on some existing local files, say, inventory, group_vars.
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html#python-api-2-0

Now I am trying to setup all data from one python code without other local files.
For `InventoryManager` I use below example.
https://gist.github.com/cbwest3/cb4e9ac16261595a82f8b4ab54629bac

For `VariableManager`, is any example that I can set up to make it equivalent to my `group_vars/windows.yml`?
(which is setting for my `windows` group machines to use `winrm` connection.)

```
ansible_user: MY_USER
ansible_password: MY_SECRET
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

Update:

I found `VariableManager` has `set_host_variable` method, which allow me to set variable for all my windows host like:

```
    for host in self.inventory._inventory.hosts.values():
        for group in host.groups:
            if group.name == 'windows':
                self.vars_manager.set_host_variable(host, 'ansible_user', r'MY_USER')
                self.vars_manager.set_host_variable(host, 'ansible_password', r'MY_SECRET')
                self.vars_manager.set_host_variable(host, 'ansible_port', '5985')
                self.vars_manager.set_host_variable(host, 'ansible_connection', 'winrm')
                self.vars_manager.set_host_variable(host, 'ansible_winrm_transport', 'ntlm')
                self.vars_manager.set_host_variable(host, 'ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation', 'ignore')
```

I cannot find better way to do this now.

Comment: Use extra_vars maybe a good idea. Like: variable_manager.extra_vars = {'ansible_user': 'MY_USER', 'ansible_password': 'MY_SECRET'}

Comment: @felixc, I tried this way that will set vars for all hosts(it is useful, thanks). for my case, I only want to set vars for `windows` group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `InventoryData` try:

```
data.add_group('windows')
data.set_variable('windows','ansible_connection','winrm')
data.add_host('host1', group='windows')
data.add_host('host2', group='windows')
```